# RSS Filter and Compile

Tags: rss, feeds

Does anyone know of a good way to compile say 20 RSS feeds and generate top news stories out of it? The idea is that we want to have a section on our wordpress site that pulls in feeds from many sources, but I want the best and most relevant articles showing up. I guess it would kind of be a similar concept to Google News.

Comment: Can you define "best" and "most relevant"?